# Align long survey text to start each row in the same position

Tags: css, html, survey

As you can see in the image below I have a survey with long answer text that takes several rows for each answer:

[image]

What I want to do is to align the rows to be aligned with the first row of each answer. Is that possible?

Comment: No HTML/CSS? We can't diagnose what we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *display* property in CSS to fix this issue. I made the survey divider a table and the label inside it a table-cell, which by default keeps all text on the same vertical line.

However, each answer is in its own divider in this example as I was unable to force the input to take the display property and use it alone. This should do the trick though, and I am sure there is a simple workaround for that, or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>List items in survey</title>
        <style>
            div.survey-answer {
                display: table;
            }

            label {
                display: table-cell;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="survey-answer">
            <input type="checkbox" id="survey-answer-1" /><label for="survey-answer-1"><b>ANSWER 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sagittis lacinia nulla, eu consequat tellus posuere at. Integer sagittis mauris quis massa tempor bibendum. Proin quam leo, tristique eu nibh non, consequat auctor risus. Pellentesque dignissim at metus a pharetra. Phasellus sit amet metus non arcu sodales hendrerit. Etiam dictum id magna pulvinar laoreet. Mauris sodales sapien non arcu molestie molestie. Proin blandit varius nisi, vel suscipit est tempor quis. Morbi posuere metus sit amet sem ultrices, eget rutrum diam aliquet. Donec vel sem eu turpis convallis aliquam vitae eget justo. Vestibulum vel ornare lacus. Nulla massa massa, tincidunt ac tristique ut, euismod a urna. Nam tincidunt orci at sapien consectetur, non gravida orci bibendum.</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="survey-answer">
            <input type="checkbox" id="survey-answer-2" /><label for="survey-answer-2"><b>ANSWER 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sagittis lacinia nulla, eu consequat tellus posuere at. Integer sagittis mauris quis massa tempor bibendum. Proin quam leo, tristique eu nibh non, consequat auctor risus. Pellentesque dignissim at metus a pharetra. Phasellus sit amet metus non arcu sodales hendrerit. Etiam dictum id magna pulvinar laoreet. Mauris sodales sapien non arcu molestie molestie. Proin blandit varius nisi, vel suscipit est tempor quis. Morbi posuere metus sit amet sem ultrices, eget rutrum diam aliquet. Donec vel sem eu turpis convallis aliquam vitae eget justo. Vestibulum vel ornare lacus. Nulla massa massa, tincidunt ac tristique ut, euismod a urna. Nam tincidunt orci at sapien consectetur, non gravida orci bibendum.</label>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**Demonstration »**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sMdj/2/)

Hope this helped you out!